Is it better to run MariaDB on multiple smaller servers or one big one?
I have three clients that all use MariaDB for their applications.
In the interest of security, I created a VM for each of them that have a 2vCPU and 4GB RAM.
But I was wondering if merging their servers would be such a bad idea, as they would benefit from a MUCH more powerful server and it would cost me a bit less in cloud fees.
What would the benefits be in power vs security?

that depends much on how isolated the server must be, would the data still be seperated after the merge are you using user grants on tbale, to keep the data seprated at a lower level.

The databases each have a separate user so I am assuming that client X's user has no way of accessing client Y's database as each user would be different. Would that be correct?

you can only grant access to tables, so if all  the tables form databse A have the same name as in databse B you can not seperate them on databse elevel, onöy at program level with an additional column database, so hat you can differentiate. But if your databses have different table names you can use the user, to allow him only access to his tables

I'm sorry, maybe I am not as well versed as I should be when it comes to this, but what I am suggesting is that in MariaDB, each client has a user with privileges over a database that has multiple tables with which they do as they please. Am I mixing up terminology?

@Cezar I suggest having separate schemas for each client, do not mix things up.

You will probably not see any difference in performance between the options you presented.

First, do you want to have resources separated between users or not? There’s really no way to limit resource consumption per user or per schema in MySQL. There are some things like number of connections but it is usually irrelevant in the grand schema of things. If you have to ensure that neither of the users can impact others, your option is to separate them using VMs.
Some kind of an alternative would be to run a separate processes of MySQL on a single VM. Then you can use system-based resource limits (cgroups for example) to impose some limitations. It is not the same as separating VMs but better than single MySQL process. On the other hand, setting up and managing multiple MySQL processes is way more complex and annoying in the long run than having single MySQL running on a single VM.
Then we talk privileges. Do users need elevated privileges or not? If yes, you can’t use single MySQL for that. If users need to have access to the logs or manage replication, that’s also a no-go. In that case you have to create a single MySQL per each of your clients.
All in all, there are many ways in which you can run MySQL or MariaDB, depending on the requirements that you have. Keep in mind that the complexity of the operations is also something you need to account for. It’s not just the VM that has its price, your time spent on managing and debugging performance problems also has its price tag.

Thank you, I think I get what you are saying. Changing the viewpoint from cost/resource to cost/management time is pretty eye-opening.
